# how to represent a piece-wise linear function using linear combination of max function

Tags: neural-networks, relu, linear-algebra

If given a piece-wise linear function and its turning points, how to represent the function using linear combination of max function?

Comment: What have you tried? You should put some effort in your questions.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/962277/first-degree-spline-interpolation-problem/1018069#1018069